# Passing blank array to a function to and populate it from there

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass a blank array to a function that will manipulate the array dependent on certain scenarios. I don't know where I am going wrong with this but I am getting the following error `Type mismatch`. Below shows how I am creating the blank array:

```
 Dim testArray(0 to 10) as string
 Dim ABredu() As String
 ABredu = Equipment(testArray)
```

Below shows the function that I have written to populate the array

```
Function Equipment(Test() As String)
     If standYes = True And .ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0 Then
         ReDim ABredu(1 To 3)
         ABredu(1) = "Pen"
         ABredu(2) = "Ruler"
         ABredu(3) = "Monitor"
     Else
         ReDim ABredu(1 To 3)
         ABredu(1) = "17-P2"
         ABredu(2) = "17-L73"
         ABredu(3) = "16-ENR"  
     End If
 End sub
```

If someone could help me or give a push in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Macro subs do not return values; only functions do that. If the `ABredu` variable was `Public` you could use `Equipment` to fill it without passing the array back but you might want to change `Equipment` to a function and construct then pass back the array.

Comment: I will edit the question here now so you can see what I have now and the error I am recieving

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: @Jeeped If the argument is passed by reference then then it can be returned with a different value regardless of if it's a sub or a function.

Comment: @SO do you know why I am getting the error described in the edited question above

Comment: @SO - bit of semantics there. Yes the macro sub is assigning/modifying the values akin to the global variable scenario I described but it is not *returning* the values. Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: Your function has no type and doesn't set a return value so you are trying to assign a variant (the default function return type) to a string variable, which gives a type mismatch. Your code doesn't indicate what you want to put in ABredu in the main program.

Comment: Yes that is the exact reason that I couldn't get it to work! I was that worried about getting the syntax for passing the array to a function I forgot to set the return value

Comment: @Jeeped Okay fair enough, just the way I read it was that you can't amend the value of an argument in a sub - but after clarification I see what you mean.

Comment: if you don't return a value, just use "byRef" method. Equipment testArray. Note Equipment(testArray) will send the variable as byVal

Answer (score 3):

Pass the array by reference as a variant.

```
Function Equipment(ByRef Test As Variant)
     If standYes = True And .ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0 Then
         ReDim Test(1 To 3)
         Test(1) = "Pen"
         Test(2) = "Ruler"
         Test(3) = "Monitor"
     Else
         ReDim Test(1 To 3)
         Test(1) = "17-P2"
         Test(2) = "17-L73"
         Test(3) = "16-ENR"  
     End If
 End sub
```

Comment: I am still recieving the erro `type mismatch` on this line of code `ABredu = Equipment(testArray)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ByRef` is the default in VBA, not only that but the function as you've presented it still makes little to no sense. What's standYes? What is .ComboBox2? Where the heck is this variable called ABredu coming from? @user3538102 might be able to enlighten us on this but as it stands I see so many errors that I don't even know where to start an answer of my own and your 'answer' is still rife with them.

Comment: standYes is just a checkbox within my userform! the if statements and all don't really pose the question, its more the syntax to passing and array to a function!

Comment: See edit above, if you refer to the array as "Test" in the argument name, then it needs to use that name throughout the scope of that procedure.

Comment: Also, you have `.ComboBox` yet there is no `With` block in your function?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach using variant arrays.

```
Sub Some_Macro()
    Dim ABredu As Variant, i As Long
    ABredu = Equipment(True, 0)
    For i = LBound(ABredu) To UBound(ABredu)
        Debug.Print ABredu(i)
    Next i
    ABredu = Equipment(False, 0)
    For i = LBound(ABredu) To UBound(ABredu)
        Debug.Print ABredu(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function Equipment(standYes As Boolean, cdLI As Long)
    Dim vEQUIP As Variant
     If standYes And cdLI = 0 Then
        vEQUIP = Array("Pen", "Ruler", "Monitor")
     Else
        vEQUIP = Array("17-P2", "17-L73", "16-ENR")
     End If
     Equipment = vEQUIP
 End Function
```

There are several ways to accomplish what you are looking for. Pick the one that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: thanks for the alternative answer but I want to keep this relatively simple so I went for the method above! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm going to make a couple of assumptions about your expected logic here, since the code in your question is a bit nonsensical.

You're trying (I think) to:

1. Create an array of strings called ABredu
2. Use a function or subroutine to populate that array based on some conditions

With that in mind, you can create the following sub

```
Sub PopulateEquipment(EquipArr() As String)
    ReDim EquipArr(1 To 3)
    If <condition> Then '<~~ Insert your own conditions here
        EquipArr(1) = "Value 1"
        EquipArr(2) = "Value 2"
        EquipArr(3) = "Value 3"
    Else
        EquipArr(1) = "AltVal 1"
        EquipArr(2) = "AltVal 2"
        EquipArr(3) = "AltVal 3"
    End If
End Sub
```

Then to populate your array using this, you need only `Dim` it and then call the subroutine, passing the variable as an argument.

```
Dim ABredu() As String
Call PopulateEquipment(ABredu)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, use an ArrayList.

```
Public arList As Object

Sub PartOne()

Set arList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Call Equipment

End Sub

Private Sub Equipment() '// No Need to pass argument as arList is of Public scope.

With arList

If standYes And Me.ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0 Then
     .Add "Pen"
     .Add "Ruler"
     .Add "Monitor"
Else
     .Add "17-P2"
     .Add "17-L73"
     .Add "16-ENR"
End If

End With

End Sub
```